# what is the accurate way to define position of a "VIEW"?

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I've tried to define where a view will be positioned using the "android:layout_marginTop" so far, which seemed easier at that time but now I've found serious problems with it. the bottom-most view is not displayed on smaller screens.

here's my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".StartActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#6CD9CE">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:scaleX="1.0"
            android:scaleY="1.0"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_transparent" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTint="#6CD9CE"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#6CD9CE"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RandomText"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot from emulator and design preview:

[Design Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHDsU.png)

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwCxT.jpg)

Comment: I would suggest study about `ContraintLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'weight' attribute or try to use ScrollView

Comment: I think weight is better approach in this case.

Comment: In the current scenario, **weight** attribute might useful but if there is any input field in the layout then you should use **scrollview** instead of **weight** attribute. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `ContraintLayout` but if you don't want to make a big change, you can set the last `TextView` to have `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` so it will take all the rest of the `LinearLayout`, set `android:gravity="bottom"` and then space it a little from the bottom with `android:paddingBottom="20dp"`

Like this:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="RandomText"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Cheers